# Ionic build succeeds but does not create .apk file

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I was always able to build from this project, this just started happening this morning. When I run `ionic build android` everything runs smoothly and the build succeeds, but the date modified on the android-debug.apk file stays the same, and I don't see my changes when I run it on a device.

Could it have something to do with messed up permissions and somehow it doesn't have permission to write the apk? I'm running Ubuntu-server 14.04.4.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been answered before but I'm adding this to let you guys know what I've tried and how it's not working anyways...

I've also faced same issue and tried several things like

```
Renaming APK file, expecting it will create new one.
Deleting build folder, expecting as usual will create new one.
opening project in Android studio, expecting it will create new one when I use it to launch the APK to device.
I've tried calling ionic prepare platform before calling ionic build.
```

The ionic build is a proxy for cordova build command.

But in this issue all of above approaches were failed.
The reason I can see behind this is because of no proper response/function of added platform to your project, as when you build it's cordova platform android's responsibility to prepare build on your command. Which is not working.
Lot of people suggests that You need to us ionic/cordova restore, this will restore your state.

Another way is you can use Android Studio's build APK option which helps you not to disturb your plugins by restore or reset commands.

Hope this helps you save your time from trying all these approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Could it that you are looking at a wrong place?
When build command is successfully finished you should see smth like below in console

```
Built the following apk(s):
        <PATH_TO_YOUR_SOURCES>/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
```

Are you checking this this location?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my post the builds were working fine before this started happening.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the problem isn't with Ionic, it's just that the changed files aren't showing up in the ftp for some reason. So now I will try and figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @mobileevangelist , ionic cordova restore can be done using command

> ionic cordova prepare

It fixed my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to

1. Open Android Studio
2. Choose Import project
3. Select YourProjectDirectory/platforms/android folder
4. Choose Build -> Build APK

Comment: I would rather use the CLI, I'm developing this on an ubuntu server with no GUI so I would have to move the whole project to my local pc in order to do that.

Comment: Then possibly you need to look into something like `gradle build -x lint` with current directory set to YourProjectDirectory/platforms/android

Comment: I tried that and nothing happened at all, no errors, messages or anything. But would that actually work? Wouldn't building it directly like that not compile the changes I've made in my www folder? It was working with `ionic build android` just fine before.

Comment: As I see it, there are 2 stages of build:  
1) **Ionic build**  
Makes project for each platform from files you provided in www folder.  
2) **Platform specific build**  
Valid project is given to specific platform build tools to get binary package for this platform.  


So after each change you need to make these two builds.